# how to retrieve images in android image view

Tags: android, android-studio

please am working on a class project which i will submit soon and i need your help.am trying to get image saved in varbinary format in my sql server 2016 into my android Image view.i have been stock at this level for a while and i need help to cross it.i have also check google and youtube but the answers i found did not help me out.other values in my database table gets retrieved except the image when i look at the log file it tels me no adapter attached skipping layout.as you will see in the code my adapter is attached.help please help. below is my codes
for connecting to the database using jtds

```
package com.example.abun.shoprite1;


import java.lang.String; 
import java.io.File;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import static java.nio.file.Files.size;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;


public class ConnectionClass {

String url;
String serverName;
String instanceName;
String databaseName;
String userName;
String password;
String port;
String sql;

ConnectionClass() {

    serverName = "192.168.80.1";
    port ="1433";
    //instanceName = "";
    databaseName = "shoprite";
    userName = "abun2";
    password = "shoprite";
}
private String getConnectionUrl() {
    // Constructing the connection string
    return url + serverName +" ;DatabaseName = " +databaseName +";user="+userName + ";password="+password +";";
}

//private String getConnectionUrl() {
// Constructing the connection string
//return url + serverName  +" ;DatabaseName = " +databaseName+"; integratedSecurity=true";
//}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    String ConnUrl;
    //String conny= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ serverName+ ":" +port+ ";"+ " ;DatabaseName = " +databaseName+"; integratedSecurity=true";
    ConnUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + serverName+ ":" +port+ ";"+ "databaseName=" + databaseName + ";user=" + userName + ";password=" + password + ";";
    Connection con =null;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnUrl);
        //con = DriverManager.getConnection(conny);
        //""+"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1/shoprite; integrated security=true"
        // Establishing the connection
        //con = DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl());
        //con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnUrl);
        if(con != null){
            System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(" no Connection ");
        }
    }catch(SQLException se){
        Log.e("ERROR--",se.getMessage());
        Log.e("ERROR--",se.getSQLState());
        Log.e("ERROR--",se.getLocalizedMessage());
        Log.e("ERROR--",se.getCause().toString());
        Log.e("ERROR--",se.getStackTrace().toString());

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException se){
        Log.e("ERROR--",se.getMessage());
        Log.e("ERROR--",se.getLocalizedMessage());

    }catch(Exception se){
        Log.e("ERROR--",se.getMessage());
        Log.e("ERROR--",se.getLocalizedMessage());

    }
    return con;
}

public boolean verifyCustomer(String username,String password)throws SQLException{
    Connection con1;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String query = "select * from Customer_Details where Customer_Name =? and Password=?";
    try {
        con1 = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con1.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        stmt.setString(1, username);
        stmt.setString(2, password);

        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    } finally {

        if(resultSet != null)
            resultSet.close();
    }
}

public boolean verifyEmployee(String username,String password)throws SQLException{
    Connection con1;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String query = "select * from Employee_Details where Employee_Name =? and Designation=?";
    try {
        con1 = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con1.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        stmt.setString(1, username);
        stmt.setString(2, password);

        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    } finally {

        if(resultSet != null)
            resultSet.close();
    }
}

public boolean insertDataCustomer(String name, String gender,String address,int phone,
                                  String DOB,String password,String email,int creditcard,String creditCardType){
    Connection con1;
    String query = "insert into Customer_Details(Customer_Name,Gender,Address,Phone,DOB,Password,CreditCardNo,CreditCardType) values( ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        con1 = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con1.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, name);
        stmt.setString(2, gender);
        stmt.setString(3, address);
        stmt.setInt(4, phone);
        stmt.setString(5, DOB);
        stmt.setString(6, password);
        //stmt.setString(7, email);
        stmt.setInt(7, creditcard);
        stmt.setString(8, creditCardType);

        long ent= stmt.executeUpdate();
        if(ent == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }catch(Exception e){
        // System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Log.e( "error here: ",e.getMessage());
        Log.e( "error here: ",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        Log.e( "error here: ",e.getCause().toString());
        return  false;
    }
}

public boolean insertDataEmployee(String ID, String name, String gender,
                                  String DOB,String Designation,String address,String email,String phone){
    Connection con1;
    String query = "insert into Employee_Details(ID,name,gender,DOB,Designation,address,email,phone) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        con1 = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con1.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, name);
        stmt.setString(2, gender);
        stmt.setString(3, DOB);
        stmt.setString(4, Designation);
        stmt.setString(5, address);
        stmt.setString(6, email);
        stmt.setString(7, phone);


        long ent= stmt.executeUpdate();
        if(ent == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }catch(Exception e){
        // System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Log.e( "error here: ",e.getMessage());
        return  false;
    }
}

public void veiwOrders()throws SQLException{
    Connection con1;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String query = "select * from Order_Details";
    try {
        con1 = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con1.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()){
            while(resultSet.next()){

            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        //return false;
    } finally {

        if(resultSet != null)
            resultSet.close();
    }
}
}
```

below is my activity class
    package com.example.abun.shoprite1;

```
/**
* Created by Abun on 5/12/2018.
*/
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresPermission.Write;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.content.Intent;
//import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class productPage extends AppCompatActivity  {

private RecyclerView mRecycler;

private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ArrayList<String> mData;
private ArrayList<ProductPageRetrive> data;
ConnectionClass db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productpage1);
    db = new ConnectionClass();


    data = new ArrayList<ProductPageRetrive>();
    mData = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0;i<30;i++){
        mData.add("new title"+i);
    }

    SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
    orderData.execute("");
    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(productPage.this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MainAdapter(data,productPage.this);
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(
            new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                    // Respond when the drawer's position changes
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    // Respond when the drawer is opened
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    // Respond when the drawer is closed
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                    // Respond when the drawer motion state changes
                }
            }
    );


    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // set item as selected to persist highlight
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    // close drawer when item is tapped
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
                    // For example, swap UI fragments here

                    return true;
                }
            });





}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String ,String,String>{
    String msg="Internet/DB_Credentials/Windows_FireWall_TurnOn Error, see android monitor in the buttom for details";
    ProgressDialog progress;
    boolean success = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(productPage.this,"Synchronising","RecyclerView loading! please wait...",true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...strings){
        try {
            Connection con = db.getConnection();
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            if (con == null) {

                msg="No Data found";
                success = false;
            }else{
                String query = "SELECT * FROM Product_Details";
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);


                resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    try {

                        data.add(new ProductPageRetrive(resultSet.getBinaryStream("Image"), resultSet.getInt("Price"), resultSet.getInt("Discount")));

                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                msg ="found";
                success=true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Write write = new StringWriter();
            //e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(write));
            //msg=writer.toString();
            success=false;
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg){
        progress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(productPage.this,msg+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(success == true){



            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }else{
            try{

            }catch (Exception e){

            }

        }
    }
}

}
```

below is the data object for the array  data;
    package com.example.abun.shoprite1;

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

/**
* Created by Abun on 6/14/2018.
*/

public class ProductPageRetrive {

private int price;
private int rating;
private String img1;
private InputStream ism;
private ResultSet rs;


public ProductPageRetrive(InputStream is, int money, int rate){
    this.ism=is;
    this.price=money;
    this.rating=rate;
}

public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(int rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getImg1() {
    return img1;
}

public void setImg1(String img1) {
    this.img1 = img1;
}

public InputStream getIsm() {
    return ism;
}

public void setIsm(InputStream ism) {
    this.ism = ism;
}
}
```

below is my adapter class
    package com.example.abun.shoprite1;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Base64;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import android.content.Context;

/**
* Created by Abun on 6/13/2018.
*/


public class MainAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> mData;
private ArrayList<ProductPageRetrive> Data;
private Context ct1;

public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> Data1){

    this.mData=Data1;
}

public MainAdapter(ArrayList<ProductPageRetrive> Data, Context ct)
{
    this.Data=Data;
    this.ct1 =ct;
}

@Override
public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.contain,parent,false);
    // set the view size, margin,padding and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int py =Data.get(position).getRating();
    String pp = py +"";
    holder.mtitle.setText(pp);

    try {
        InputStream is = Data.get(position).getIsm();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("photo1.jpg"));
        byte[] content = new byte[1024];
        int size = 0;
        while((size=is.read(content))!=-1){
            os.write(content,0,size);
        }
        os.close();
        is.close();
        //Picasso.get().load("file:photo1.jpg").into(holder.img);

        Picasso.get().load("file:photo1.jpg").into(holder.img);


    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    /*byte[] decorde = Base64.decode(Data.get(position).getImg1(),Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap mp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decorde,0,decorde.length);
    holder.img.setImageBitmap(mp);*/

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Data.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mtitle;
    public TextView mtitle1;
    public ImageView img;
    public View layout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        layout = itemView;
        mtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mtitle);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imaging);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What error is shown in logcat ?

Comment: no adapter attached skipping layout

Comment: Don't include all your code..just the relevant parts.

Comment: ok...the log cat tells me no adapter attached.looking at the code you can see that an adapter is attached.please help

Comment: i wiil appreciate any help given...thanks

Comment: Please post the logcat output

Comment: Are you sure your "data" size is not zero?